# I can only execute calibre as root (with sudo). What should I do to be able to execute it without root privileges?

Tags: permissions, sudo, calibre

I have installed `calibre`, but now I can only execute it with

> `sudo calibre`

What should I do to be able to execute it without root privileges, that is, without `sudo`?

Another problem associated with that is that all files and directories generated by calibre are owned by root.

Comment: How did you install it, `sudo apt-get install calibre` ? or some other means?  My experience is that apt-get install is less prone to cause similar things as above.

Comment: I followed the instructions I found in the calibre site: http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Comment: That is, sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"

Comment: I am no sure if that will be the solution, but I will try it later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. I simply had to change permissions of the directories `/opt` and `/opt/calibre` so that any user can access to them. Now I can execute calibre without root privileges by simply writing

> `calibre`

and all files and directories generated by calibre are owned by my user.

Answer (score 0):

*(moved from comment above)*

I have no idea about how calibre works, there seems to be a lot involved - a good load of dependencies for starters. Unless you have a very specific reason to keep the very latest version...

`sudo calibre-uninstaller` seems to be the easiest way out
- then use Ubuntu Software Center or maybe `apt-get install calibre` instead.

It isn't the latest (1.41.x) but 1.25.0 - so might miss a thing or two - but will most likely be a lot easier to get running.